# NoSuchMethodException in android?

Tags: android, nosuchmethoderror

what is the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch`

following error ,
when will it occur ,

how to rectify that

Comment: clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - java.lang.NoSuchMethodException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913970/java-java-lang-nosuchmethodexception)